# Apache 2.4 linker errors on windows using VS 2008

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, compilation, linker-errors

**Question: Is there any manual/steps on how to build Apache for windows? The official documentation isn't sufficient.**

I've tried to compile Apache HTTP Server 2.4 on windows using Visual Studio 2008 Professional on Windows 7 Service Pack 3, but with no hope at all!!
Already tested same steps with Apache HTTP Server 2.2 and had successful build process.

I don't know what's wrong, or what's missing. Here it is followed steps:

```
Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"

cd C:\path\to\httpd-2.4.2

perl srclib\apr\build\lineends.pl

perl srclib\apr\build\cvtdsp.pl -2005

cd srclib\zlib
nmake -f win32/Makefile.msc LOC="-DASMV -DASMINF -I." OBJA="inffas32.obj match686.obj"
MT -manifest zlib1.dll.manifest -outputresource:zlib1.dll;2

cd ..\..\srclib\openssl
perl Configure VC-WIN32 enable-camellia disable-idea
ms\do_nasm
nmake /f ms\ntdll.mak

Open Apache.dsw with VS9 "Yes to All" to the "convert projects" question, Select relase win32
Now build InstallBin
Test your build
```

Required libraries already in place:

```
srclib\apr
srclib\apr-iconv
srclib\apr-util
srclib\openssl
srclib\pcre
srclib\zlib
```

As I said, all Apache HTTP Server **2.2** compilations are successful, while all Apache HTTP Server **2.4** is **NOT**.

This is the most occuring error, repeated over 100 times:

```
fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\..\release\libhttpd.lib'
```

Other errors:

```
fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\release\mod_proxy_balancer.lib'
fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\core\release\mod_watchdog.lib'
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pcre.h': No such file or directory    
fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\ide\devenv.COM"' : return code '0x1'
error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing Makefile project actions"
```

**Note: I've noticed that there's multiple .mak file missing from the Apache 2.4 package, including the httpd.mak & others. I think that's big part of the problem.**

Any suggestions?

Environment: Windows 7 | Visual Studio 2008 | Cygin | Apache HTTP Server 2.4 Source | APR/APR-UTIL/APR-ICONV/ZLIB/OPENSSL

Comment: fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\..\release\libhttpd.lib' -- search for the file check if it exists and if it does check if it exists in the path mentioned

Comment: It doens't exist, and that's the problem!! I suppose (don't know if right or wrong) that this file is generated by the build process, and it's not built!! But there's similar files with similar names, see: libhttpd_cl.idb & libhttpd_cl.pdb of course in addition to libhttpd.dsp & libhttpd.vcproj ... Any suggestions?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try compiling each dependency before you compile and the dependencies of each dependency before you try to compile Apache it self.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a bit. I presumed (Probably in error) that InstallBin or BuildAll would Build all the necessary dependencies. (I'm trying to build in VS2015)

Comment: Sometimes, there are circular dependencies, so to avoid this, the least needed project is removed from the main project dependency, you have to build that one project manually.

Since I have no idea now which project that is, You have to right click them one by one and choose build.

Comment: P.S. This answer was in 2012 I don't know if it's relevant anymore and I haven't built apache since.

Comment: Thanks, I've just started with compiling Apache using MSVC 2015 and am getting a varied array of red and yellow in my outputs which I'm getting to understand ~_~

Comment: You are most welcome, feel free to comment here if you need anything.